# Hide entire listview with items count = 0

Tags: android, listview

I need hide my `ListView` dynamically when the number of items is 0.
The `ListView` has items. I can remove the item with a button and update the list. But I want to hide the list and show a `TextView` when the number of items is 0.

I think I need set it in the adapter, but how ?

Update: I was unclear. I want hide it dynamically. I do know how to hide, I just don't know how do it dynamically.

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Answer (score 2):

good practice is to set empty view for listview as below

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.textView));
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Visibility of your `listview` to either `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` when `adapter.getCount()` returns 0

Answer (score 1):

If you have made your custom adapter then you can do something like this:

```
if(getCount() ==0 ) {
    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

If you have not made custom adapter then check the array which is handling your list items. If thats zero then set your list invisible and make your textview visible.

```
if(arrayname.size == 0) {
    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Use This And Change adapter and layout according to your requirements

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.activity_list, listArray);

 //Check Here about listView Items

    if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
        mlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```